# Influx of users including the content of their post twice in their question

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-review, questions

As the title says, I've noticed an influx of users recently where they've posted a question where the content of the post is duplicated. If this was a one-off I'd think it were a user error, but these are from different users.

I've not seen this occur on answers, so I suspect it could be related to the question wizard. Here are a few examples I've found lately, which were all created from the wizard: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74445835/1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74434761/1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74443528/1), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74373422/1).

I don't post questions, and I don't want to try posting one to try to replicate the problem, so the best I can do is post a bug report, which might lead someone to find the issue.

---

Some commenters feel that it's likely due to lack of users following instructions (which I'm sure would not surprise any of us) and as the wizard has 2 boxes they copy the content from one into the other instead of reading. If this is the cause, though not a "bug", it's certainly not desirable behaviour. As such it would be beneficial that some *check* is done to ensure that the text in the 2 boxes is sufficiently different. I've therefore added [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to this post as well, to address this eventuality.

Comment: Since there are [2 text boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCxD4.png) and some users just don't read the instruction...

Comment: ^ Yep, I doubt that's a bug. And it's not too surprising since I've already seen some users write their entire question in the title and then repeat it in the body. The system could enforce that the text in both fields should be different, but again, I doubt that would solve the problem. Some would just remove a few letters from one of the fields.

Comment: I've definitely seen people do that prior to the Wizard, @41686d6564standsw.Palestine .

Comment: Perhaps calculating the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the texts in both fields (accompanied with a clear message if it doesn't pass the threshold) would be a decent solution to this?

Comment: @Larnu prior to the wizard, it was to pad out the content and bypass the filter. But it was relatively rare. Post-wizard, I've seen a lot more and like Andrew, I think it's the two boxes.

Comment: If that is th case, maybe the staging ground will help the matter, @VLAZ , though I would suggest that being able to have the same content in the 2 boxes, if not a bug, is undesired.

Comment: @Larnu fully agreed that I do not desire seeing questions with the same content twice.

Comment: yeah, it really, really should check for dupes here. Might not be a bug in the traditional meaning, but it's a mechanic resulting in consistently unexpected behavior increasing the work curators have to do. Not good for anyone involved

Comment: In case there is a need for more examples: [here is one of the \*ahem\* better ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B42SJ.png). Second line, just like the first but it started with `#`

Comment: And some users wonder why their content gets downvoted, @Vlaz ...

Comment: Unfortunately even the best question wizard does not cause people to no longer be in an artificial hurry. Perhaps we should try to make Stack Overflow more zen. Add a little color and some pictures of shrubbery, elevator music in the background, hide Waldo somewhere...

Comment: @Gimby replace "review your question" button with "meditate on your question". The placeholder in the search field at the top should read "search for enlightenment". :D